# Search Results Page filter by page title

Tags: plugins

How can i edit the search results page embedded in OceanWP theme, so that the page with a title similar to the word i entered in the search bar show up first or at least highlighted?

Comment: Is this just a matter of presentation, or are you trying to change / improve the search results that it generates? I'd guess that the theme just uses WordPress's built-in search, not provides its own, so it's probably a case of finding a replacement search plugin. I don't know one to recommend sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I think you are looking for a plugin, I think this answer might help some people who search for a similar answer. If you have access to your functions.php file, you can easily make this happen.

First we'll alter the `orderby` parameter of the search query in order to filter them by page title. Here is a snippet that I tested and will alter you search results page and order it by title, ascending.

```
//Filter the search by title for posts
function filter_search_by_title($query){
    if($query->is_search() && $query->is_main_query()){
      $query->set('post_type', array('post'));
      $query->set('orderby', 'title');
      $query->set('order', 'ASC');
  }
  return $query;
}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'filter_search_by_title');
```

Next, regarding the highlighting, here is a piece that will go through your `the_excerpt` and `the_title` on the search results page, and will add a `<strong>` around each instance of the string searched. Obviously you can change that to whatever you'd like in order to style it.

```
function highlight_search_results($content){
     if(is_search()){
       $search_string = get_query_var('s');
       $keys = explode(" ",$search_string);
       $content = preg_replace('/('.implode('|', $keys) .')/iu', '<strong class="highligh-search">'.$search_string.'</strong>', $content);
     }
     return $content;
}
add_filter('the_excerpt', 'highlight_search_results');
add_filter('the_title', 'highlight_search_results');
```

Hope that helps!!